# Python - Beautifulsoup - Only data from final scraped link being outputted to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape sports schedule from multiple links on a site. The URL's are being found and printed correctly, but only data from the last scraped URL is being outputted to console and text file.

My code is below:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def makesoup(url):
    cookies = {'mycountries' : '101,28,3,102,42,10,18,4,2,22', 'user_time_zone': 'Europe/London',  'user_time_zone_id': '1'} 
    r = requests.post(url,  cookies=cookies)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
   
def linkscrape(links, savefile):
    baseurl = "https://sport-tv-guide.live"
    urllist = []
    
    for link in links:
        finalurl = (baseurl+ link['href'])
        urllist.append(finalurl)
        print(finalurl)
        
    for singleurl in urllist:
        soup2=makesoup(url=singleurl)
        g_data=soup2.find_all('div', {'id': 'channelInfo'})
        c_data=soup2.find_all('div', {'class': 'liveOtherStations clearfix'})
    
    with open(savefile ,"w") as text_file:
        
        for match in g_data:
            try:
                event =  match.find('div', class_='title full').text.strip()
            except:
                event = ""
            try:
                extrainfo=  match.find_previous('div', class_='pt-5 text-center').text.strip()
            except:
                extrainfo = ""
            try:
                startime =  match.find('div', class_='time full').text.strip()
                print("Time; ", startime) 
            except:
                startime = "Time element not found"
            try:
                dateandtime = match.find('div', class_='date full').text.strip()
                print("Date:",  dateandtime)
            except:
                dateandtime = "Date not found"
            try:
                sport = match.find_previous('div', class_='sportTitle').text.strip()
                print("Sport:",  sport)
            except:
                sport = "Sport element not found"
            try:
                singlechannel = match.find('div', class_='station full').text.strip()
                print("Main Channel:",  singlechannel)
                print("-----")
            except:
                singlechannel = "Single Channel element not found"
            
            extra_channels = []

            for channel in c_data:
                try:
                    channels = match.find('div', class_='stationLive active col-wrap')
                    print("Extra Channels:",  channel.text)
                    extra_channels.append(channel.text)
                except:
                    channels = "No channels found"
                    print(channels)
                    extra_channels.append(channel.text)
                print("-------")
            
            if extra_channels:
                for channel in extra_channels:    
                    text_file.writelines("__**Sport:**__" +':' + ' '+ sport +" \n"+"__**Competitors:**__" +':' + ' '+ event+" \n"+ "__**Extra Info:**__" +':' + ' '+ extrainfo+" \n"+"__**Match Date:**__" +':' + ' ' +dateandtime +" \n"+"__**Match Time:**__"+':' + ' ' +startime +" \n"+ "__**Main Channel**__"+':' + ' '+singlechannel+" \n" + "__**Channels**__"+':' + ' '+channel+" \n"+'-' *20 + " \n")
            else:
                text_file.writelines("__**Sport:**__" +':' + ' '+ sport +" \n"+"__**Competitors:**__" +':' + ' '+ event+" \n"+ "__**Extra Info:**__" +':' + ' '+ extrainfo+" \n"+"__**Match Date:**__" +':' + ' ' +dateandtime +" \n"+"__**Match Time:**__"+':' + ' ' +startime +" \n"+ "__**Main Channel**__"+':' + ' '+singlechannel+" \n" + "__**Channels**__"+':' + " \n"+'-' *20 + " \n")
            


            
def matches():
    
    dict = {"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/darts":"/var/scripts/output/darts.txt", 
   "https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/mma":"/var/scripts/output/mma.txt",   
   "https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/wwe":"/var/scripts/output/wrestling.txt", 
   "https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/motorsport":"/var/scripts/output/motorsport.txt", 
  "https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/rugby-union":"/var/scripts/output/rugbyunion.txt", 
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/rugby-league":"/var/scripts/output/rugbyleague.txt",  
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/cricket":"/var/scripts/output/cricket.txt",  
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/tennis":"/var/scripts/output/tennis.txt",  
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/snooker":"/var/scripts/output/snooker.txt",  
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/golf":"/var/scripts/output/golf.txt",  
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/netball":"/var/scripts/output/netball.txt",  
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/basketball":"/var/scripts/output/nba.txt",  
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/baseball":"/var/scripts/output/mlb.txt", 
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/ice-hockey":"/var/scripts/output/nhl.txt", 
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/nfl":"/var/scripts/output/nfl.txt", 
"https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/boxing":"/var/scripts/output/boxing.txt"}
    
    for key,  value in dict.items():
        soup=makesoup(url=key)
        game_check = soup.find('div',  class_='alert alert-info')
        if game_check is not None:
            with open(value ,"w") as text_file:
                text_file.writelines("No games found for event")
        else:
            linkscrape(links=soup.find_all('a',  {'class': 'article flag',  'href': True}),  savefile = value)

matches()
```

This provides me with the following output

[image: wrongoutput]

I have old code below, which works correctly and outputs all the data from each of the scraped URL's from the main page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def makesoup(url):
    cookies = {'mycountries' : '101,28,3,102,42,10,18,4,2,22', 'user_time_zone': 'Europe/London',  'user_time_zone_id': '1'} 
    r = requests.post(url,  cookies=cookies)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
   
def linkscrape(links):
    baseurl = "https://sport-tv-guide.live"
    urllist = []
    
    for link in links:
        finalurl = (baseurl+ link['href'])
        urllist.append(finalurl)
        # print(finalurl)
        
    for singleurl in urllist:
        soup2=makesoup(url=singleurl)
        g_data=soup2.find_all('div', {'id': 'channelInfo'})
        c_data=soup2.find_all('div', {'class': 'liveOtherStations clearfix'})
        for match in g_data:
            try:
                hometeam =  match.find_previous('div', class_='cell40 text-center teamName1').text.strip()
                awayteam =  match.find_previous('div', class_='cell40 text-center teamName2').text.strip()
                print("Competitors; ", hometeam +" "+ "vs" +" "+ awayteam)
            except:
                hometeam = "Home Team element not found"
                awayteam = "Away Team element not found"
            try:
                startime =  match.find('div', class_='time full').text.strip()
                print("Time; ", startime) 
            except:
                startime = "Time element not found"
            try:
                event=  match.find('div', class_='title full').text.strip()
                print("Event:",  event)
            except:
                event = "Event element not found"
            try:
                dateandtime = match.find('div', class_='date full').text.strip()
                print("Date:",  dateandtime)
            except:
                dateandtime = "Date not found"
            try:
                sport = match.find('div', class_='text full').text.strip()
                print("Sport:",  sport)
            except:
                sport = "Sport element not found"
            try:
                singlechannel = match.find('div', class_='station full').text.strip()
                print("Main Channel:",  singlechannel)
                print("-----")
            except:
                singlechannel = "Single Channel element not found"
            for channel in c_data:
                try:
                    channels = match.find('div', class_='stationLive active col-wrap')
                    print("Extra Channels:",  channel.text)
                except:
                    channels = "No channels found"
                    print(channels)
                print("-------")


            
def matches():
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/mma")
    linkscrape(links= soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'article flag',  'href' : True}))
    

    
        
        
matches()
```

I believe the issue may have been the below:

```
with open(savefile ,"w") as text_file:
```

so I tried to move this inside the  `for link in links:` for loop, but the output was the same (only data from the last URL being scraped from the main page being outputted).

Thanks to anyone who can provide assistance with solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct the problem does lie in this line of code:

```py
with open(savefile, "w") as text_file:
```

Then `"w"` in that line of code means to open the file for "write" which seems like what you want but what you actually want is `"a"` for "append".  "Write" will erase and start writing the file from the beginning but "append" will add it to the end of the file. Try this:

```py
with open(savefile, "a") as text_file:
```

Comment: thanks. This worked. I just needed to move the while code inside the ```    for singleurl in urllist:``` loop for the correct output.